# Connection reset by Peer pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, azure, tcp, pymongo

I have some documents which I have to fetch from mongodb and set it to memcache. Here is the code

```
import memcache
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = mongo_client.job_db.JobParsedData
jobs = db.find().sort("JobId", 1)

def set_to_memcache_raw(jobs):
    print("Setting raw message to memcache")
    count = 0
    for item in jobs:
        job_id = item.get('JobId')
        job_details = item.get('JobDetails')
        if job_id.strip():
            count += 1
            memcache_obj.set(job_id, job_details, time=72000)
            if count % 1000 == 0:
                print("Inserted {} keys in memcache".format(count))
            if count >= 1000000:
                break
```

But, after some odd number of iterations the code throw this error -

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 450, in receive_message
    self.sock, operation, request_id, self.max_message_size)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 137, in receive_message
    header = _receive_data_on_socket(sock, 16)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 164, in _receive_data_on_socket
    chunk = sock.recv(length)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memcache-poc.py", line 56, in <module>
    elapsed = time.time() - t0
  File "memcache-poc.py", line 52, in main
    jobs = db.find(query)
  File "memcache-poc.py", line 17, in set_to_memcache_raw
    print("Setting raw message to memcache")
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1114, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1056, in _refresh
    self.__max_await_time_ms))
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 873, in __send_message
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 905, in _send_message_with_response
    exhaust)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 916, in _reset_on_error
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 136, in send_message_with_response
    response_data = sock_info.receive_message(1, request_id)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 452, in receive_message
    self._raise_connection_failure(error)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 550, in _raise_connection_failure
    _raise_connection_failure(self.address, error)
  File "/home/dimension/.virtualenvs/docparser/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 211, in _raise_connection_failure
    raise AutoReconnect(msg)
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I have gone through links such as

[pymongo-errors](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html)

[mongodb-TCP keep-alive](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#does-tcp-keepalive-time-affect-mongodb-deployments)

[why-does-pymongo-throw-autoreconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809168/why-does-pymongo-throw-autoreconnect)

Their is no question of socket inactivity in the above code as my jobs object is an iterator and every time next() is called on this object it will fetch the next document (from mongo itself)

I have mongodb installed on Azure cloud and my TCP keep alive for the instance is 7200 seconds. I get this figure by firing this command

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time
7200
```

Do having a try cacth block over the for loop helps in this case

Comment: It doesn't hurt to try yourself than asking.

Comment: can you write, at what exact line you are getting the exception? and if you are inserting multiple items in each loop, why don't you create a list of items to insert and them try inserting them at once (this is not related to solving above error, just a suggestion)

Comment: The code is throwing exception at "for item in jobs:" line. Also memcache doesn't support setting multiple keys at a time, so I have to write single entry in memcache in each loop.

Comment: @AnuragSharma The answer of the SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705007/mongodb-connection-reset-by-peer might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the information below for the issue from the `pymongo` api document [here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html), the exception need to be handled manually.

> `exception pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect(message='', errors=None)`
>
> Raised when a connection to the database is lost and an attempt to auto-reconnect will be made.
>
> In order to auto-reconnect you must handle this exception, recognizing that the operation which caused it has not necessarily succeeded. Future operations will attempt to open a new connection to the database (and will continue to raise this exception until the first successful connection is made).

I searched some existing solution for the issue, please see below.

1. A code snippet from [here](https://gist.github.com/anthonywu/1696591#file-graceful_auto_reconnect-py) for gracefully handling the PyMongo `AutoReconnect` exception.
2. Using a middleware named [`MongoDBProxy`](https://github.com/arngarden/MongoDBProxy) to automatically handle `AutoReconnect` exception.

Hope it helps.